# Checking for a value in an array with ternary operator

Tags: javascript

I'm a little confused here. Can someone explain to me why a ternary operator doesn't work here?

If I do this using regular if-statement, it works

```
function check(arr, el) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === el) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3));
```

If I use a ternary operator, I get false for a truthy condition

```
function check(arr, el) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    return arr[i] === el ? true : false;
  }
}

console.log(check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3));
```

For contrast, here is a simple ternary check function

```
function checkTernary(num1, num2) {
  return num1 === num2 ? true : false;
}

console.log(checkTernary(2, 3)); // false
console.log(checkTernary(3, 3)); // true
```

I suspect that checking for a false condition outside of the loop is the answer. As in, I am evaluating the entire loop  for a false. But evaluating each iteration for a true??? I just need a clear explanation on this and a possible conversion to ternary if it can be done

Comment: You're returning `false` immediately, rather than waiting for the end of the loop. Consider looking into `Array#some` and `Array#every`

Comment: Then again, in this case you're just re-inventing `Array#contains`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol interesting. Are you saying using every() to check the array instead of a for loop?

Comment: as soon as you return anything from your function, it stops executing. since the first element in the array is not the one being checked for, the ternary skips true and returns false and that's that.

Comment: @JSONaLeo you're referring to the ternary, right?

Comment: yes the example function you posted using the ternary operator

Comment: @JSONaLeo Thanks. That actually helps a lot clarifying when and when not to use a ternary.

Comment: @LOTUSMS awesome! happy to help and good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the return statement is executed the function doesn't proceed further and returns a value.

In the first case the code will `return` `false` only if the condition is `true` if condition is false then it will proceed further. In the first case the `function` will return `false` after the end of the loop.

In the second example there is no condition to execute `return` so it will return in first iteration and function will not execute further.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying. Run a loop to iterate and check every value. For every condition evaluated, it check to see if it's true. If it is, it executed the `return true`. But if that iteration is false, it jumps out of the loop to return false?   I guess, what confuses me more is that the return false is not part of the condition logic inside the loop evaluation

Comment: @LOTUSMS _"But if that iteration is false, it jumps out of the loop to return false?"_. No it doesn't jump out of the loop to return. It do nothing and continues to the next element. It will reach the last `return false;` when all the elements will be checked.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. ok, so here's a wrench. Wouldn't putting the return false in an else statement inside the loop be expected to work? Becasue it didn't lol I guess I am trying to make some sense  to when I should consider returning outside of the loop or inside and when a ternary is useful or isn't. Pavan's answer did make a great point about the checking the entire array unnecessarily, which is not ideal if I was checking an array of YouTube videos in the entire YoutTube API. It could go on for months!

Comment: @LOTUSMS 1) You seem to be a new programmer. I would say just don't over think on just single thing. `return` means end of function. Outside the loop inside the loop. Anywhere in the function. 2) Just don't try to make use of things which are not best for the purpose. In the above case ternary operator is not useful at all. 3) If you put the `return false;` is `else` block inside the loop. Even then the code will return in first iteration.

Comment: You've caught me! Is it that obvious? lol. Yes, for a very long time I was a UI/UX designer and I'm slowly working my way into UI/UX development. I'm not completely incompetent with JS, but every now and then I get stuck in something. But I'm learning. And I'm hungry for more. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

A function can only return once, so we can't put them in a loop. But if you really want to use a ternary operation you can do it like this

```
function check(arr, el) {
    let check = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        check = arr[i] === el ? true : check;
    }
    return check
}
```

but keep in mind that it will loop over all the elements in array even after it finds an equal element so an even better solution would be your first solution, which is

```
function check(arr, el) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === el) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`arr[i] === el ? true : false` is an `expression` which will be evaluated to a value, true or false.

`return arr[i] === el ? true : false` is a `return statement` which can only be executed once and will return value of the expression `arr[i] === el ? true : false` at the first time of loop.

The most important point is that any `return statement` can only be executed once, or zero times which means not be executed. Nothing else will affect this rule as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

One Liner with ES6

```js
const checkTernary = (num1, num2) => num1 === num2;

console.log(checkTernary(2, 3)); // false
console.log(checkTernary(3, 3)); // true
```